# Thread and Loop.prepare() issue

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I can't get this to work.
The problem is, the Thread is never notified that the listener is done searching for a location.

```
final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setTitle("Procurando");
    progress.setMessage("Localizando o dispositivo.");
    progress.show();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GeoLocationHandler handler = new GeoLocationHandler();
        try {
            synchronized (handler) {
                Looper.prepare();
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,          0,handler);
                handler.wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        progress.dismiss();
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(handler);
        double lat = mLocation.getLatitude();
        double lng = mLocation.getLongitude();
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + lat + "," + lng +    "&daddr=-22.858114, -43.231295"));
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}
thread.start();
```

Here is the class implementing LocationListener:

```
private class GeoLocationHandler implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mLocation = location;
    notify();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where you are starting that thread.

Comment: Bharat Sharma, just edited my question and added the thread.start(), it's rigth after I finish creating the run method.

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Bharat Sharma, just edited my question and added the thread.start(), it's rigth after I finish creating the run method. Thank you for the answer.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: if you have already solved problem then either delete this question or mark an answer otherwise someone will marks as not useful..

Comment: But the problem is not yet solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution, not quiet the way I wanted, but it works.
Created progress dialog as a field and dismissed it through a handler.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ibMap:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Procurando");
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Localizando o dispositivo.");
    mProgressDialog.show();
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mGeoHandler);
        break;
    default:
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Nothing yet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private class GeoLocationHandler implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mLocation = location;
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

}

private class MyHandler extends Handler {

@Override
public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    double lat = mLocation.getLatitude();
    double lng = mLocation.getLongitude();
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + lat + "," + lng + "&daddr=UFRJ,RJ"));
    startActivity(intent);
    super.dispatchMessage(msg);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're not calling `notify()` from a synchronized block.  If you want to try to get your original solution working, try this

```
private class GeoLocationHandler implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      mLocation = location;
      synchronized(handler){
          notify();
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Synchronize on 'this' instead since you do not have a reference to 'handler'. I also suggest using `notifyAll()` instead of `notify()`.

Comment: @Nate, true re not having a reference to the handler, but you need to synchronize on the same monitor you're calling wait/notify on or you're going to end up with the same results. Ultimately the OP needs to either synchronize on `this` or the `handler` reference but it needs to be the same thing both times